# Does a mutex locked thread use cpu time?

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex, sleep, cpu-usage

I try to change a sleep() function in a thread to pthread_cond_timedwait() so suspension can be stopped from another thread if it is needed. My question is about efficiency. Because as I understand when using sleep() the thread is passivly waiting so no additional cpu usage occures. What does the scheduler do with a mutex locked thread? Is it the same as with sleep() or is it actively waiting in this case? Because I use potentially a lot of threads which would be suspended for a long period of time (minutes, hours or maybe days) I fear I might use unnecessary cpu time.

Comment: Question is unclear. Are you interested in condition variables or mutexes?

Comment: Sorry my understanding is that if a thread is waiting for a condition variable it is in a mutex lock. I'm new to that whole concept so I might be wrong @SergeyA

Comment: Not really. It is waiting on a signal that variable was changed. The mutex is only auxiliary, as it prevents several threads try to access the variable once the condition has been signaled.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the best way to distill down the behavior of pretty much all multi-threaded OSes without regard for sweeping generalizations:

A thread is usually represented as a data structure that stores context. The scheduler keeps a list of thread structs which are currently "runnable." If a thread is taken off the "runnable" list, it will not be scheduled to run on any available CPU.

A mutex is usually implemented as a reference to a thread struct which owns the mutex, and a list of threads which are waiting for it. A thread cannot be on both a wait list, and the scheduler's runnable list simultaneously. Thus a thread waiting on a mutex cannot be scheduled, and cannot take CPU resources.

There are caveats and details. For example on a multi CPU system, the mutex implementation might actually allow for a short period of "spin waiting" before being placed on a wait queue. This covers cases where a lock might only be held briefly by another thread on another CPU, in which case a full context switch might be more expensive. In general though, you can assume a blocked thread will not be runnable from the scheduler's point of view.

Answer (score 0):

No, waiting on a mutex doesn't use CPU time. Mutexes are implemented in the kernel, so it puts the thread to sleep until the mutex is unlocked.

Comment: Maybe.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19863734/what-is-pthread-mutex-adaptive-np  Other OSes also use adaptive mutexes that spin for a bit before going to sleep.